# How to fill marked empty line with specific symbol?

Tags: notepad++

Let say I have an empty line in my text document like line `2` on the screenshot below:

[image]

This line has no characters. I can mark some area in this line using <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard key and left mouse button: colored gray on the screenshot above.

How can I fill this area with specific character (for example, hyphen)?

Thanks

Comment: Negative answer : You can't.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^$`
- Replace with: `-----------` as many as you want
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # begining of line
$       # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I don't want to tick lot of `-`.  It's not convenient: I already marked my area. By this way I can just put the caret on the first position in the line and press `-` without releasing some time.

Comment: @Jackdaw: OK, I see what you want but I'm afraid it's impossible to fill the marked area :-(

Comment: Yes, I am looking to find out some way to use markers. Like we can mark some rectangle in document, then use mouse <Right click>+ select `lowercsase` from the popup and all text in the marked rectangle will be changed to _lowercase_. I just trying: may be you right and this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're referring to completely empty lines or lines containing whitespace characters only (space, tab etc.)

Either way if you're using Notepad++, open the replace box (Ctrl+H) and at the bottom-left change the "Search Mode" to "Regular expression".

To match only completely empty lines type `^$` in the "Find what" box. If you want to match lines that are either empty or containing only whitespace character then type `^\s*$` in the box. Enter whatever you want to go into that line (e.g. hyphen) in the "Replace with" box, then click "Replace all".

Comment: I have completely empty lines, no spaces, no tabs.

Comment: To avoid having to put in a bunch of repeated symbols, e.g., "--------------", or "===========", put them in the clipboard. If you use a clipboard manager such as Windows own or CopyQ, you can keep that permanently in memory, and paste with a keypress, such as  Ctrl+Fn*n* in CopyQ.